# I tried to use nginx as a reverse proxy within a docker container, but it didn't work

Tags: docker, nginx

I build a nginx image with this content in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx
```

The content of the nginx.conf file is the following:

```
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream server1 {
        server localhost:8081;
    }
    upstream server2 {
        server localhost:8082;
    }

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        location /server1/ {
            proxy_pass http://server1;
        }
        location /server2/ {
            proxy_pass http://server2;
        }
}

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

}
```

I have two node servers running on port 8081 and 8082 which working properly when visited directly. However when I visit http:localhost:8080/server1/ or http:localhost:8080/server2/ the response says can't GET server1/server2 respectively.

I find out that in the /etc/nginx/modules folder within the container there is no "upstream" related module listed there. Could it be that the "upstream" function not supported because of the absence of the related "upstream" module?

Can someone tell me how to fix the problem? Thank a lot.

Comment: You node servers are running in the container as well? Keep in mind that `localhost` in the container refers to the container itself, not to the host.

Comment: The two node servers are running in another two containers. Could that be the problem? If so, could you tell me how to fix the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is definitely the problem. You could create a network (see `docker network --help`), attach all three containers to it (see `docker run --network`) and refer to the two servers by using their container name as host name.

Comment: What changes should be made in the nginx.conf file to use the two node container names? Thanks a lot.

Comment: change the `localhost` in the `upstream` clause.